# ACL Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3, acl

Existe algum tutorial para criar a estrutura de de ACL (permissions e roles) para Laravel 5.3?
Tentei utilizar o pacote zizaco/entrust, porém mesmo seguindo os passos de configuração do github não funcionou.

Comment: Dá algum erro ?

Comment: Se eu fosse você, nesse momento, faria por si só um tabela de roles uma tabela user_roles (**N:M**) faria a relação faria o cadastro de roles e o cadastro de user_roles e depois disso um `middleware`, porque, esses pacotes muitas vezes tem mais do que precisa. A Lógica inicial é essa e tem um [github de exemplo](https://github.com/laracasts/Users-and-Roles-in-Laravel) sendo as duas classes. Não é que não deva utilizar algum dia, tem pacotes excelentes por exemplo esse: [artesaos/defender](https://github.com/artesaos/defender)

Answer (score -2):

Amigo, acabo de implementar pra laravel 5.3, tentei utilizar o zizaco porém é um pacote voltado para o 5.2 e ainda digo mais tem muito mais do que precisa. 
Dê uma olhada no que eu comecei a fazer, pode ser que ajude https://github.com/pabliciotjg/ACL_LARAVEL

Comment: Muito obrigado Thiago, vou estudar o sistema que você fez.
Agradeço novamente a ajuda.

Comment: Já que voltei a mexer com o ACL concluí essa parte todinha já comitei o restante, se vc der um git pull vai ver que ele está completo já, com permissions roles e a permissão específica pra cada usuário, pra testar corretamente vc além de usar a versão mais recente do mysql tem que executar as migrations e os seeds ok?? qq dúvida estamos ai!!